# Javascript - How to create an image using canvas based on pixel colors on the site?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a site where it has div tags with background colors, and I use relative positioning to move them all together so it looks like an image. I moved them so its exactly on the top left of the page.

How do I create an image out of it, so like if there was a button, when it gets clicked, it creates an image of width 608px and height 105px, and then asks the user if they want to save it or open it or close it (standard download box)?

I would need to get the pixel color starting from index (0,0) right?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using background images on divs, just draw images onto a canvas. Then take a look at this http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-save-drawing-as-an-image/